# Pkgconfig cant find a package

Tags: cmake, pkg-config

I am using pkgconfig in cmake to link to an external library. Even though there exists a exteral_package.pc file (with apparently correct information), cmake is throwing me an error.

The CMakeLists file looks something like this:

```
project(juicer)
set(VERSION 1.0)
# Find packages
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
find_package(Tracter REQUIRED)
```

And the FindTracter file looks like this:

```
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(TRACTER REQUIRED tracter)
```

Error:

```
-- checking for module 'tracter'
--   package 'tracter' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:279 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:333 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  cmake/FindTracter.cmake:10 (pkg_check_modules)
  CMakeLists.txt:22 (find_package)
```

I am new to using CMake and your help is very much appreciated. 
Thanks
Akshat

Comment: Have you checked whether the pc file is found by manually calling `pkg-config`?